# Continuity and convexity of $F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^xf(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and convex. Show that $$F:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$$$F(x)=\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^xf(t)dt$$
>   is continuous and convex.

My attempt: Continuity it's straight forward, since $f$ it's continuous it's also integrable which implies that $\int_{0}^xf(t)dt$ it's continuous over $(0,+\infty)$ and therefore $F$ it's the product of two continuous functions (since $1/x$ it's continuous over that same interval) hence $F$ itself it's continuous.

When it comes to convexity I tried calculating the second derivative of $F$, I got: $$F'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(f(x)-\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^xf(t)dt\right)$$
$$F''(x)=\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\int_{0}^xf(t)dt-\frac{2}{x}f(x)+f'(x)\right) $$

Since $\frac{1}{x}$ it's positive on the desired interval I tried analyzing the expression inside the parenthesis but without much success (I noticed I haven't used anywhere that $f$ is convex so that must be the key but I'm not sure how to utilize it). I also tried proving the inequality $F(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y)\leq \lambda F(x) + (1-\lambda)F(y) $ but after substituting $F$ with it's definition the result looks messy and complicated... Any help?

Comment: I sugguest to invoke MVT: $F(x)=f(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in[0,x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the change of variable $t=xy$. Then your integral becomes
$$
\int\limits_0^1 f(xy)dy
$$
And its second derivative  in $x$ Is
$$
\int\limits_0^1 y^2f’’(xy)\,dy
$$
Which is nonnegative.

Comment: I'm probably missing something very simple but, how do you perform that substitution, shouldn't you get $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}xf(xy)dy$ ?

Comment: If $y=t/x$, then $\int_0^x f(t)\textrm{d}t=\int_0^1 xf(xy)\textrm{d}y.$ Now notice that there is a division by $x$ in your definition of $F$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Why does the upper boud become $1$? that's the thing confusing me

Comment: Because if $y=x$, then $t/x=1$. Basically you need to recall that the substitution formula really is $\int_a^b g'(x)f(g(x))\textrm{d}x=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(y)\textrm{d}y$. To see this, simply apply the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to see that if $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$, then $F(g(x))$ is an anti-derivative of $g'(x)f(g(x))$.

Comment: Second derivative need not exist. You can just use the definition of a convex function instead of differntiating twice. Also differntiating inside the integral is not always permitted.

Comment: Right. I was assuming smoothness for the sake of simplicity but convexity follows by definition. Actually since $f$ is convex it is continuous and $F$ is differentiable at least once but not twice generally.

Answer (score 5):

Convex functions need not be twice differentiable so your approach is not valid. $F(x)=\int_0^{1} f(xy)dy$ by the substitution $y=\frac t x$. This makes it obvious (from definition) that $F$ is convex: $$F(tu+(1-t)v)=\int_0^{1} f((tu+(1-t)v)y)dy$$ $$ \leq \int_0^{1} [tf(uy)+(1-t)f(vy) dy =tF(u)+(1-t)F(v).$$